# How to index a hierarchical data?

Tags: algorithm, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have some hierarchical data that can be represented via two data structures.

The first one is the multi-level JSON object like below:

```
[
    { 
        "text": "Item 1, "children": [
            {"text": "Nested item 1"}, 
            {"text": "Nested item 2"}] 
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 2", "children": []
    }
]
```

And the second structure is an array. Items of this array are bound by `id-parentId`.

```
[
    {id: 1, text: "Item 1", parentId: null},
    {id: 2, text: "Nested item 1", parentId: 1}
]
```

I need to filter these data by some substring.

To implement this functionality I want to create some search index. And then provide the filter operation for the created index.

The main reason to create the search index is usage a single filtering algorithm instead of two different approach to filter hierarchical data and `id-parentId` list.

So, the question is what format should have the search index? Currently, I use something like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, text: "item 1", parentKey: null, childrenKeys: [2,3]},
    {id: 2, text: "child 1", parentKey: 1, childrenKeys: []},
    {id: 3, text: "child 2", parentKey: 1, childrenKeys: []}  
]
```

Pros: each item has links to parent and children.

Cons: I have to generate keys for items manually if the source data structure is hierarchy.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: The multi-level JSON structure doesn't have item keys by default. So I have to create keys for each node from source JSON object and then add it to the search index.

Comment: Please provide some concrete usage scenarios for such an index. For example, will you only search by full string values, or also by substrings? Can these substrings be located anywhere in the string, or only at the beginning or at the end of a string?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions, such as data to index size ratio?

Comment: I'd like to find items that contain some substring. For example, if substring is 'abc', **item.text: 'abcd'** should be added to the search result.

Comment: I don't have restrictions you described.

Comment: what if `item.text` is `'xabcd'`? Should the substring `'abc'` still be found?

Comment: Yes, it should be found

Comment: Why exactly do you need an index here? What's wrong with just traversing the JSON structure?

Comment: Because I have two different data structures(plain & hierarchy). I've described it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take care for both formats at once, it's not worth the trouble to deal with mapping to a single format.

Below I used the Array.prototype.reduce function (I could of used Array.prototype.filter, but then I would of had to concatenate result arrays from the recursive calls and/or add function args to the bind).

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5q4cdevt/

```
/* @this {string} search value */ 
function reduceContains(result, obj) {
    if(obj.text.indexOf(this) >= 0) { 
        result.push(obj); 
    }
    if(obj.children) {
        obj.children.reduce(reduceContains.bind(this), result);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log([
    { 
        "text": "Item 1", "children": [
            {"text": "Nested item 1"}, 
            {"text": "Nested item 2"}] 
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 2", "children": []
    }
].reduce(reduceContains.bind("Nested"), []));

console.log([
    {id: 1, text: "Item 1", parentId: null},
    {id: 2, text: "Nested item 1", parentId: 1}
].reduce(reduceContains.bind("Nested"), []));
```

Comment: Thank you for response @Louis Ricci! `Array.prototype.reduce` is the nice idea!